# Highcharts export web war does not work on Weblogic server

Tags: java, highcharts, export

I have followed the following guide (for a java environment) and encountered a problem: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server

The highcharts-export-web application returns empty images when it's deployed on a WebLogic server. An image object is returned by the server but it contains no data. When the same war is deployed on a Jetty server everything works perfect.

Turning on the logging information did not reveal anything. Everything seems to be going fine, but I'm getting "empty images"

Does anybody have a clue why this could be happening and how I could be able to fix this?

- Weblogic 12.1.2
- Highcharts 3.0.5

Comment: No error messages in the log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default WebLogic registers its own URLStreamHandler to handle http URLs. This results in that the Connection silently returns and empty files being returned from the server.  The solution is to get in a reference to Java's default URLStreamHandler instead of the one from WebLogic. Follow these steps

1. Alter this file: highcharts-export\highcharts-export-convert/src/main/java/com/highcharts/export/server.Server.java

Change line 94,95 from

```
URL url = new URL("http://" + host + ":"
+ port + "/");
```

to

```
sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler handler = new sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler();
URL url = new URL(null, "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/", handler);
```

1. Goto the folder java/highcharts-export
2. Update your local maven repository, Run: mvn install
3. Goto the folder java/highcharts-export/highcharts-export-web
4. Create a new .war file, Run: mvn clean package